# Open all links in browser without jquery- Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

I found this solution on stackoverflow. But how is this possible without jquery?

```
$('a[href^=http]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var activity = new MozActivity({
    name: "view",
    data: {
              type: "url",
               url: $(this).attr("href")
          }
    });
 });
```

Comment: What did you end up doing? Please update us on your progress/solution

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I used your solution. Thanks a ton. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct port using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^=http]');
for(var i=0,len=els.length;i<len;i++){
   els[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var activity = new MozActivity({
             name: "view",
             data: { type: "url", url: this.href}
        });
    },false);
}
```

This will not work if you're dynamically adding links, for that you need to add the listener when you add the link or use event delegation.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to open links from within your app in the Firefox web browser on Firefox OS? Then I'd recommend using target="_blank" instead to avoid the dependency on JavaScript.

If you want that for all links in your app, just add `<base target="_blank">` to the  section of your code.